# Can't import files from parent directory

Tags: python

I can't seem to import python files from a parent directory. I ran the following commands in bash:

```
echo 'token="AAA111"' > config.py
mkdir scenarios
echo $'from .. import config\nprint(config.token)' > scenarios/test.py
python3 scenarios/test.py
```

But this gave me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scenarios/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .. import config
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

What did I do wrong?  How can I get `scenarios/test.py` to grab content from `config.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative imports (dots) refer to position within a [package](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#packages) not necessarily any directory. *)

If you want to import a module from a parent directory, you would need to add it to the module search path, e.g.:

```
...
echo $'import config\nprint(config.token)' > scenarios/test.py
PYTHONPATH=. python3 scenarios/test.py
```

---

*) If you've had the following tree:

```
.
└── mypkg
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── config.py
    └── scenarios
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test.py
```

With `from .. import config` in `mypkg/scenarios/test.py` as in your example, then this would have worked (called from parent above `mypkg/`):

```
python3 -c 'import mypkg.scenarios.test'
```